# Duplicate entry 'mect200' for key 'Primary'

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I am making a student database which contain the `course id`, `course name`, `credits` of each course, pass fail statement and the `grades`. 
My aim is to update the information. I wrote the following code:

```
private void Update_bttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
        string query = "update studentdata.semestre1 set CourseId ='"+ this.crsId.Text +"',CourseName='" + this.crsName.Text + "',Credits ='" + this.credits.Text + "',CourseStatement= '" + this.comboBox2.Text + "',Grade = '" + this.Grades.Text + "';";
        MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, ConDatabase);


        MySqlDataReader myReader;


        ConDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Information Updated");
        while ((myReader.Read())) { }
        ConDatabase.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

When I try to enter the information I get this error

**`Duplicate entry 'the course id i entered' for key 'Primary'`**

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

from the error Course ID seems to be your primary key

and moreover you dont have a where clause in your update statement

your query should read something like this

```
string query = "update studentdata.semestre1 
                set CourseName='" + this.crsName.Text + "',
                Credits ='" + this.credits.Text + "',
                CourseStatement= '" + this.comboBox2.Text + "',
                Grade = '" + this.Grades.Text + "'
                where CourseId ='"+ this.crsId.Text +"',;";
```

Comment: yes the CourseId is my primary key. i tried your code but a new error occured which is :
**_you have an error with you SQL syntax; Check the manual that correponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near ' set CourseName = math1 . credits =3 , CourseStatement = 'pass', Grade ='100'.where' at line 1_**
do you have any idea about the solution ?

Comment: @marc gravell can you help me ?

Comment: why are you getting  "." dots in between (math1 . credits =3) instead of "," ?

Comment: oh no it's , typing fault :S @kathrik Ganesan